# SLComposeViewController won't set initialText for SLServiceTypeFacebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

It seems as a bug in Social framework, it won't set the initial text for Facebook service type. This is my implementation using Swift:

```
let view = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
if view.setInitialText("Some text") {
    NSLog("Success")
} else {
    NSLog("Failure")
}
view.addURL(NSURL(string: "https://google.ro"))
self.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**What it works:**

- The URL shows up for both, Facebook, and Twitter
- The initialText works correctly just for Twitter

**What is doesn't work:**

- The initialText won't show up for Facebook, even though the code above outputs "Success"

## Update 2

It seems like Facebook really doesn't want developers to set the initial text of a message when Sharing as that it's impossible even with their SDK. In the app I was implementing I've chosen screenshots from the app (uploaded as images) for letting the user share their progress on Facebook.

## Update

The solution is to use the Facebook SDK for iOS, that feature of Social framework is not supported by Facebook anymore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not a bug, Facebook doesn't allow it anymore.

Use of the iOS share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy, including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill. In the context of the share sheet, this means apps may not pre-fill the share sheet's initialText field with content that wasn't entered by people earlier in their use of the app.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook dose't allow to pre fill message anymore.
For more info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill)

Saying that, if you use native Facebook sdk it **won't** solve your problem, because Facebook will not publish your app.
So as written on Facebook guidelines, the only solutions that you have are:

1. Populate the user message parameter with content that the user manually entered earlier in your app's flow.
2. Your app’s composer can include a call-to-action that disappears when people start to write a post. For example, Facebook's composer uses grey scale text to ask “What's on your mind?” that disappears when people start to write.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is an iOs 8.3 bug.
Before I updated to that version it was working correctly. :-(

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. I will use Facebook and Twitter SDKs instead. They are far better and more complex.