# connecting a UITextField to an SLComposeViewController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to set the default text of an SLComposeViewController to what a user inputs into a UITextField by converting it to a string, but it isn't showing up in the SLComposeViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
var userTextInput: String = ""

@IBAction func shareFacebookButton(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook){
        let facebookPost = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        facebookPost!.setInitialText(userTextInput)
        self.present(facebookPost!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error")

}
}
```

I've tried to make a String bur I need to get it to use the variable textField the String in the variable userTextInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but before proceeding that

> **Facebook dose't allow to pre fill message anymore**, for more information you can get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870514/slcomposeviewcontroller-wont-set-initialtext-for-slservicetypefacebook)

you can directly append the textfield value to share, for e.g

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook){
    let facebookPost = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    facebookPost!.setInitialText(textField.text)
    self.present(facebookPost!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    print("Error")
}
```

**update**

you can check if textfield has text or not, if yes you can share in facebook , for e.g'

```
if !textField.text.isEmpty
{
 if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook){
    let facebookPost = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    facebookPost!.setInitialText(textField.text)
    self.present(facebookPost!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: All working. Thanks! But it sucks that I'm going to have to try and use the Facebook SDK

Comment: Is there any way that I can force it to use the old Facebook SLComposeViewController instead of the new one, because you can use that if you don't have the Facebook app installed. It only uses the new one if you have the Facebook app installed, so the old Facebook compose view controller still exists. It uses that one when I am running it in a simulator without Facebook installed.